# Что означает пустой файл /var/run/reboot-required?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Что означает пустой файл /var/run/reboot-required?

Comment: Ядро обновляли?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Нет, сейчас проверил - файл появляется после простой установки обновлений пакетов, причём абсолютно пустой. В MOTD перезагрузить систему не просит. После перезагрузки системы - файл исчезает. Где искать к нему хоть какой то мануал? Везде разное пишут. Кто то пишет что сам файл - это флаг, что мол система требует перезагрузки, а кто то пишет что в файле должны быть перечислены пакеты требующие перезагрузки текущих процессов или сообщение о необходимости перезагрузки системы.

Comment: А unattended-upgrades у вас выставлена? ( /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades )

Comment: этот файл означает, что каким-то процессом была выполнена команда `touch /var/run/reboot-required` (или какой-нибудь более низкоуровневый её аналог). нынче принято в каталог `/var/run` (или тот каталог, куда указывает эта ссылка) монтировать что-нибудь типа *tmpfs*, т.е., хранится его содержимое в оперативной памяти.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Да, unattended-upgrades включен и настроен по умолчанию.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Короче ничего не понятно с этим файлом. Как просто определить когда система нуждается в перезагрузке после установки обновлений?

Comment: @Hipster Ч.Е.З. Я считал до сего дня, что apt при установленном автообновлении так запрашивает перезагрузку при обновлении ядра, но сейчас почитал - не обязательно.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov В `50unattended-upgrades` есть строки: // Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if
//  the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade 
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false"; Т.е. хотя бы можно сделать вывод что важно само наличие файла `reboot-required` (а не его содержимое) и хотя бы можно сделать вывод что `unattended-upgrades` его всё таки создаёт. Осталось разобраться с APT.

Comment: Короче, проверено экспериментальным путём. Файл `reboot-required` создаётся и при ручном обновлении через `apt upgrade`.